# Change new Sites' default language

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams

Whenever a new MS Team is created in my company's tenant, looking into the underlying Sharepoint's resources everything appears in Dutch e.g. group names "Bezoekers" and "Eigenaars" instead of "Visitors" and "Owners", OneNote notes are named "Notitieblok" and have dutch date rather than the english equivalent, site landing page url is "/Introductiepagina.aspx" etc

When I go to https://MYCOMPANY.sharepoint.com/ and into Site Settings > Language Settings, it states "The default language for this site is Dutch". I'm guessing that EVERYTHING that is created in our sharepoint site is plagued with this language setting... (Ticking "English" in Language Settings made no difference)

**Question**: is there ANY way to make (at least) future Team sites be created in English? For example, some way to change the "Team Site" Template to be in English?

Answer (score 1):

When creating new team site, you could choose the default language. As the below picture shows:

[image]

Comment: Main problem is that people mostly create teams inside MS Teams - and there you don't get a choice for language. In any case, while this suggestion does make most Group names be in English (but not all), it apparently doesn't create a "full" team structure: the new site doesn't appear in Teams (and it doesn't have a "General" folder in documents etc)